# Is there any literature or articles which expand more on Einstein's thoughts about Dostoyevsky's novels?

Tags: physics, einstein

It is a well known fact that he admired Dostoyevsky even more than scientists. I'm looking for things like, Einstein's opinions about his religious discourse? What did he think of his bold statements on the natural sciences and how it's progress removed the "sacred?" Was Einstein enamored on the themes of organized religion in Dostoyevsky's fiction or more so his philosophical deism?

Comment: Please briefly state the extent of your research up to this point. Have you consulted B.G. Kuznecov, "Einstein und Dostojewski". In: B.G. Kuznecov, "Einstein: Leben — Tod — Unsterblichkeit." Basel: Birkhäuser 1977, pp. 386-424

Comment: [Letter from Einstein to Heinrich Zangger dated March 26, 1920](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol9-doc/561): "Ich lese Dostojewski (Brüder Karamasow). Es ist das Wunderbarste, was ich bisher in der Hand hatte."

Comment: [Letter from Einstein to Paul Ehrenfest dated April 7, 1920](https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol9-doc/572): "Ich lese mit Begeisterung die Brüder Karamasow. Es ist das wunderbarste Buch, das ich je in der Hand gehabt habe. Leider bin ich schon bald fertig damit."

Comment: @njuffa You are Godsent, thank you so much! I will try my best to translate whatever I can.

Comment: For the work by Kuznetsov, see also: Boris Kuznetsov, "Einstein and Dostoevsky." London: Hutchinson Educational, 1972.

Comment: Alexander Moszkowski interviewed Einstein in 1919 and 1920 and published "Einstein – Einblicke in seine Gedankenwelt", Hamburg: Hoffmann und Kampe 1921. In it one [finds](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/moszkows/einstein/chap009.html) on p.185: "Wenn Sie aber fragen, wem ich zurzeit das stärkste Interesse entgegen bringe, so kann ich darauf erwidern: »es ist Dostojewski!« Er wiederholte den Namen mehrmals mit gesteigertem Akzente. Und um jeden denkbaren Einwand wie mit einem Keulenhieb niederzuschlagen, ergänzte er: »mir gibt Dostojewski mehr als irgend ein Wissenschaftler, mehr als Gauss!«"

Comment: @njuffa Late, but thank you dearly for the extended information, I greatly appreciate it. They were all exactly what I was looking for.. You're a gem.